# Finding edges for licence plate

Tags: opencv, image-processing, machine-learning, edge-detection

I am doing some research on licence plate detection, I find it hard to detect edges of some licence plates where the intensity difference between the car background and the licence plate is not much. In other words the intensity difference between them is unidentifiable by human eye.

Is there a way to find the rectangular number plate in such scenario.

Below is a sample image of the car.

[image]

I have tried Canny edge detector with different thresholds, Tried many other edge detectors but no help.

Could anybody please suggest

Comment: sure there are ways: 1. train where a vehicle has the license plate. 2. detect the vehicle and detect the vehicle model. 3. use 1. but that's not practical :D

Comment: thanks Micka for the reply, I analyzed the situation but I came with few difficulties, 1) Training a licence plate position in a vehicle can be bit difficult with the possibility of vehicle being too far or too near in the frame. secondly identifying the vehicle then extracting the rectangular region and then the licence plate position sounds convincing but is computationally expensive.

Comment: what I wanted to say: if you can't distinguish colors of lp and surrounding, it just isn't possible to extract edges since there are no visual edges. For most computer vision tasks, the human eye+brain are by fast the top-end of what is possible, so if you can't see the difference with your eyes+brain it is very unlikely to find an algorithm that will "see" it (and still work with different images). But in theory you can say: "yes, there are ways to find the plate" but just in (neither practical nor realistical) theory.